# Find and replace token in string

Tags: java

Found lots of examples on string.replaceall but I cannot figure out how to use regex to solve my problem. I am looking to find and replace all occurrences of the string [reset_token] within my message.

Code I have so far:

```
String message = "Your new token is [reset_token]";
String newbody = replaceDelimiter("^[reset_token]", "mynewtoken");

public String replaceDelimiter(String delimiter, String message) {
        return message.replaceAll(delimiter, message);
 }
```

I would like the result to be "Your new token is mynewtoken"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `replaceAll` here, as your pattern is not really a regex, but is static. Simple `replace` would work fine:

```
String newbody = message.replace("[reset_token]", "mynewtoken");
```

And also you don't need that extra method wrapping your `replace` call.

Answer (score 3):

You need `replace()` instead as it replaces the string token as is:

```
String message = "Your new token is [reset_token]";
String newbody = message.replace("[reset_token]", "mynewtoken");
```